# CSS bug in text input field - MSIE7

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have an input text in a form that has a problem in MSIE7.
When the text field is filled and I continue typing, the background starts scrolling left along with the text.

This is the form when the text field is filled

[image]

The background image, a white rectangle with rounded corners, scrolls left with the text, leaving the black background.

This is the CSS for this text field:

```
  border: none;
  background: url('/wp-content/themes/pokerbuddy/images/field.png') top left no-repeat; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 20px; 
  padding: 0px; 
  font-size: 80%;  
  color: #399;  
  display:inline;
```

Is there any way to solve this in MSIE7?

Comment: If it's only IE7 and there isn't an easy fix, I'd be tempted to ignore it. The usage stats for IE7 are dropping off a cliff, and will continue falling in the months to come.

Comment: I agree with @Spudley for the most part. However I would add an IE7 specific entry to remove the background-image all together. Everyone else gets the good stuff, IE7 gets a plain white box because that's how they like it.

Answer (score 0):

```
input{overflow:hidden;}
```

Don't know if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with this line.

```
background: url('/wp-content/themes/pokerbuddy/images/field.png') top left no-repeat;
```

Don't you mean

```
`background: url('/wp-content/themes/pokerbuddy/images/field.png') top left repeat-x;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to solve this, but it's a bit of a pain. You shouldn't put the textfield in the same div with the background image. It should be more like this (example of HTML structure):

```
<div style="background-image: url('/wp-content/themes/pokerbuddy/images/field.png');>

<div class="textboxStylesHere" style="(specify width, maybe overflow hidden)">
</div>

</div>
```

Pain, but it works.